# Java regex to match only words in double square brackets

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to do this:
I have this kind of text (i.e. a file):

`[[dadasd sadasd sdsd ad asddd]] [[dasdsd]] dsdsd [[dsdas]] ... [[dd ssas dd]]`

I want only the sentences between double square brackets. How can I solve this with java?

```
//This one is not working:
    String patternStr = "(.*)\\[\\[(.*)\\]\\](.*)";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

        // Set the input
        matcher.reset("[[sdasd]] ddd [[ddssssssssssss]] vvvddd [[dd]] asdasda [[asdsa]] ");
...
```

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 5):

You want the following regex:

```
\[\[(.+?)\]\]
```

which then translates to a Java string as:

```
\\[\\[(.+?)\\]\\]
```

PowerShell test:

```
PS Home:\> [regex]::Matches("[[sdasd]] ddd [[ddssssssssssss]] vvvddd [[dd]] asdasda [[asdsa]] ", '\[\[(.+?)\]\]') | ft -auto

Groups                               Success Captures             Index Length Value
------                               ------- --------             ----- ------ -----
{[[sdasd]], sdasd}                      True {[[sdasd]]}              0      9 [[sdasd]]
{[[ddssssssssssss]], ddssssssssssss}    True {[[ddssssssssssss]]}    14     18 [[ddssssssssssss]]
{[[dd]], dd}                            True {[[dd]]}                40      6 [[dd]]
{[[asdsa]], asdsa}                      True {[[asdsa]]}             55      9 [[asdsa]]
```

Comment: Tim: I took that out now, given the examples they posted. If they anticipate different input then they should have said so.

Comment: String patternStr = "\\[\\[[^\\]]+\\]\\]";
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternStr);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");

  // Set the input
  matcher.reset("[[sdasd]] ddd [[ddsssss sssssss]] vvvddd [[dd]] asdasda [[asdsa]] ");
  boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
  if (matchFound){
...
Only the first, groups.count = 0 ... :S

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. It worked for me here: https://regex101.com/r/gD8fV3/3

Answer (score 5):

You regex simply modified: `\[\[(.*?)\]\]` or this one: `\[\[([^\[\]]*)\]\]`

So result sentences are in group No `1`

Result:

[image]

Or use this regex: `(?<=\[\[)[^\[\]]*(?=\]\])` with lookahead and lookbehind.

Result:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't match anything... I need to get only the senteces between double square brackets...
Input: [[dsdasð d d d]] asjdiajd [[ððð]]
Output: dsdasð d d d,
ððð

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[+(.*?)\\]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[[sdasd]] ddd [[ddssssssssssss]] vvvddd [[dd]] asdasda [[asdsa]] ");
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

It will output:

```
sdasd
ddssssssssssss
dd
asdsa
```